# How can i use in laravel other cipher other than the standards AES-128, AES-256?

Tags: laravel, encryption, lumen

i want to use other ciphers other than AES-128 / AES-256 which are standard hard coded into `\vendor\laravel\lumen-framework\config\app.php` and even `Encrypter` or `McryptEncrypter` use those.

Where i have to make changes so it can use other supported ciphers/modes , documentation provided dont have any information..

*phpinfo()*

```
mcrypt support  enabled
mcrypt_filter support   enabled
Version 2.5.8
Api No  20021217
Supported ciphers   cast-128 gost rijndael-128 twofish cast-256 loki97 rijndael-192 saferplus wake blowfish-compat des rijndael-256 serpent xtea blowfish enigma rc2 tripledes arcfour
Supported modes cbc cfb ctr ecb ncfb nofb ofb stream
```

`lumen version` `5.1.*`

Comment: You can extend the `HashServiceProvider` and use your own method. The [Extending The Framework](http://laravel.com/docs/5.0/extending#container-based-extension) section from the Laravel documentation actually explains this exact case. That should apply to Lumen as well.

Comment: @Bogdan wrong provider; you want the encryption one, not the hashing one.

Comment: @Amelia true, my bad :).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You would need to create your own implementation of `Illuminate\Contracts\Encryption\Encrypter`

Create a new service provider for your implementation.  You can follow `Illuminate\Encryption\EncryptionServiceProvider` as a loose guide.

Replace the service provider `Illuminate\Encryption\EncryptionServiceProvider::class,` in `app/config.php` for the one you just created.

If you didn't change the first parameter in the `singleton()` function and left it as `encrypter`, that should be all you need to do.  If you did modify it, you also will need to create a new facade and update the `aliases` array in `app/config.php`.